# How to get information from 2 different tables in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, subquery

I am trying to write a query for my sports pick application. I want to display all the information from one table, along with 2 columns from another table. I can write the query that selects all the information from one table, but I am having a difficult time writing the query to add the 2 rows to my answer. Here are the two tables that I am using. This is all in Postgresql by the way.

I want to select everything from this table.

```
 Table "public.weekly_stats"
 Column  |         Type          |     Modifiers      
---------+-----------------------+--------------------
 week_no | integer               | not null
 game_no | integer               | not null
 home    | character varying(40) | 
 away    | character varying(40) | 
 spread  | double precision      | not null default 0
 winner  | character varying(40) | 
 Indexes:
"weekly_stats_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (week_no, game_no)
Foreign-key constraints:
"weekly_stats_away_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (away) REFERENCES team(name)
"weekly_stats_home_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (home) REFERENCES team(name)
```

And then I want to display the wins and losses for each team. That uses this table...

```
 Table "public.team"
 Column |         Type          |     Modifiers      
--------+-----------------------+--------------------
 name   | character varying(40) | not null
 wins   | integer               | not null default 0
 losses | integer               | not null default 0
 Indexes:
  "team_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (name)
Referenced by:
TABLE "weekly_stats" CONSTRAINT "weekly_stats_away_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (away)
```

I can select all the information from the first table

```
Select week_no, game_no, home, wins, losses, away, wins, losses, spread, winner from weekly_stats inner join team on name.team = weekly_stats.team;
```

Comment: @developerwjk what are you talking about? That post was 6 years ago. Why are you being rude I just asked a question :(

Comment: How would I display the wins and losses twice? I want to be able to display the wins and losses for the home team and the away team

Comment: @developerwjk I understand where you are coming from. I updated my code. Do you understand how I would display wins and losses for both the home and away team? Can you even do that?

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. Just trying to get you to post the query where you tried to join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL you posted is trying to use a field `weekly_stats.team` which doesn't exist.  The teams are in `weekly_stats.home` and `weekly_stats.away` and since you have two of them, you need two joins.

And to join the same table twice, you need to give it an alias.  Here this is done by adding `team1` or `team2` after the actual name of the table in the joins:

```
Select 
 weekly_stats.week_no, 
 weekly_stats.game_no, 
 weekly_stats.home, 
  team1.wins, 
  team1.losses, 
 weekly_stats.away, 
  team2.wins, 
  team2.losses, 
 weekly_stats.spread, 
 weekly_stats.winner 
from weekly_stats 
inner join team team1 on team1.name =  weekly_stats.home
inner join team team2 on team2.name =  weekly_stats.away ;
```

Inner join will work. If there is any possibility that the table `team` might be missing a team, you could change it to `left join` which will give you a `NULL` for the wins/losses where data is missing in the `team` table.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Whats the difference between join and inner join? Without your answer I wrote this same exact thing just without the inner word. Would this change anything significant?

Comment: @ryan, `join` and `inner join` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want:

```
SELECT `weekly_stats.*`, SUM(`team.wins`), SUM(`team.losses`) 
FROM `weekly_stats` 
INNER JOIN `team` 
ON `team.name` = `weekly_stats.team`
```

If I misunderstood you, I'm really sorry.